# Firebase Clouding Messaging : Call subscribeToTopic method multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM for [Topic Messaging on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging?hl=en).

If I call the `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news")` multiple times to subscribe 'news' topic, what will happen?

I spent my time searching for it but I couldn't. I'm using that method in my MainActivity so It's called every time when app is launched. In my experience It's not problem to get push messages and I couldn't find out any problems yet. But I wanna know it exactly when I call it multiple times.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can only be subscribed to a topic once.

Additional calls to `subscribeToTopic()` for the same topic are essentially no-ops, they make no difference.

Comment: Thanks for answering and editing my question nicely :)

Comment: While it is good to know that this is the case it would be even nicer if this answer had a link to authoritative documentation where such things are explained.  Either it is me not finding things or else these matters have not been clearly documented by Google.